# An elf, a goblin, and a _____ walk into a bar

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

In the *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* film, there is a section where Newt Scamander and Tina go into a pub (tavern) full of wizards for rumours.  In this pub, they meet a house-elf barkeep (who is much shorter than humans), as well as Gnarlack, a goblin (about the same size as humans) who gives them information.

There is a short scene in that part of the film where the house elf hands a drink to **a humanoid creature who is much larger than humans**.  What is that creature?  Is it a giant?  A troll?  Something else?

Comment: Gnarlack is the barkeep.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### A giant

From the script:

> *ANGLE ON A HOUSE-ELF serving a drink to a giant, whose hand dwarfs the mug he is handed.*
>
> <sup>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* (2016)</sup>

Comment: where did you find the script?

Comment: Also, how did the giant get into a bar?

Comment: Also, what's the punch-line?

Comment: @lois6b My [local purveyor of books and book-like objects](https://www.pottermore.com/news/fantastic-beasts-and-where-to-find-them-screenplay-announcement)

Comment: @pete would be: An elf, a goblin, and a giant walk into a bar ... and there is no more bar to walk into ...

Comment: @lois6b On the contrary, it's suddenly an open bar.

Comment: @Lilienthal where you can see the nightsky

Comment: @Pete: If it's a wizarding joke, I imagine they'd go with "... the wizard ducks".

Comment: @Hurkyl - If it's a limerick, the last line would probably rhyme with "Expelliarmus"...

Comment: I'm going to tell myself that was a half-giant, like Hagrid. A real giant from the books would have taken up way more space than that bar had.

Comment: @Pete: my guess was that the barkeep asks "Whoa, is this a joke?", and the goblin replies "Worse. It's a StackExchange question."

Comment: @Snow - ... the elf and the goblin just got nasty knocks on the head. The giant didn't notice, but the bar will never recover.